# var_dump возвращает false при пустой строке

Tags: php, pdo

У меня есть скрипт, который должен возвращать кол-во 0 или 1 или true, 
который проверяет, есть ли в базе такой пользователь или нет. Форма регистрации на мероприятие.

```
$sql = "SELECT 1 FROM `users_for_events` WHERE `user_event_id`= ? AND `user_event_email`= ? LIMIT 1";

$result = $this->queryExec($sql, array($events_id,$registerData['useremail']) )->fetch();

var_dump($result);
```

Проблема в том, что когда пользователя такого нету, вардамп возвращает false

Comment: Чтоб запрос возвращал количество нужно писать `select count(smth)` в запросе... а запрос возвращает `false` в случае когда не нашел ничего в БД...что и есть в вашем случае

Comment: а вы бы не могли на примере показать, я ту наколдовал, у меня кажется и запрос не правильный в phpmyadmin ne prohodit

Comment: Каком примере? Алексей же все понятно написал... Надо `SELECT COUNT()` делать. Т.е. в Вашем случае `$sql = "SELECT Count(user_event_id) FROM users_for_events WHERE user_event_id= ? AND user_event_email= ? LIMIT 1";`

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, этот код никакого *количества* не возвращает.
И для этой задачи возвращать и не должен.

РНР - язык с динамической типизацией. И возвращаемое FALSE будет приравнено 0 при любых проверках кроме строгих. Равно как и непустой массив, возвращаемый в случае существования юзера, будет приравнен к TRUE.

Так что этот код работает именно так, как надо.

И никакого count здесь даром не нужно. Поэтому не надо слушать дурных советов, а надо оставить этот код как есть. Все он показывает правильно.